# an error or something else in ubuntu 16.04 command bash

Tags: command-line

please explain me what does this means.
this is an error or what?

```
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/rohit/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/Downloads/lkl'
```

Comment: Please tell uus what you were doing so we can try to explain...

Comment: i am installing a keylogger "lkl" with terminal and this comes out.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 1):

No it is not *in itself* an error - it is purely informational:

> If you use several levels of recursive make invocations, the ‘-w’ or
>   ‘--print-directory’ option can make the output a lot easier to
>   understand by showing each directory as make starts processing it and
>   as make finishes processing it. For example, if ‘make -w’ is run in
>   the directory /u/gnu/make, make will print a line of the form:
>
> ```
> make: Entering directory `/u/gnu/make'.
> ```
>
> before doing anything else, and a line of the form:
>
> ```
> make: Leaving directory `/u/gnu/make'.
> ```
>
> when processing is completed.

See [The ‘--print-directory’ Option](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/_002dw-Option.html#g_t_002dw-Option) in [Recursion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recursion.html#Recursion) section of the GNU `make` documentation.